# Adding Product Categories to Product Categories pages

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add product categories side bar to my product categories pages
An example of my current setup.

On my shop page I have a little product categories section that displays all the product categories. When a user clicks on the it takes them to respective category. My only issue is that once they get taken to that category the the product categories on the side vanishes. I am trying to figure out how to retain that product categories section on the left of the page every time the user goes to a different product category.

Any help would be highly appreciated on this.

Thanks